# Angular APP_INITIALIZER continues to delay application initialization even after the return of a promise

Tags: angular

I used APP_INITIALIZER in my Angular 9 application after following this tutorial on [JWT Authentication with Refresh Tokens in Angular 9](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/22/angular-9-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens) by **Jason Watmore** and I encountered a problem after implementing APP_INITIALIZER, my application keeps running ad infinitum without displaying the page.

I use Angular CLI 9.1.7 and Bootstrap 4.3.3.

Here is my code :

> App.Module.ts

```
...
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { appInitializer } from './_herlpers/app.initializer';
import { JwtInterceptor } from './_herlpers/jwt.interceptor';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './_herlpers/error.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appInitializer, multi: true, deps: [AuthService] },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> AuthService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
    this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get userValue(): User {
    return this.userSubject.value;
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrl}/users/refresh-token`, {}, { withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(map((user) => {
        this.userSubject.next(user);
        this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
        return user;
      }));
  }

  private refreshTokenTimeout;

  private startRefreshTokenTimer() {
    // parse json object from base64 encoded jwt token
    const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(this.userValue.jwtToken.split('.')[1]));

    // set a timeout to refresh the token a minute before it expires
    const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);
    const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now() - (60 * 1000);

    this.refreshTokenTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.refreshToken().subscribe(), timeout);
  }

  private stopRefreshTokenTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.refreshTokenTimeout);
  }
}
```

> appInitializer.ts

```
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';

export function appInitializer(authService: AuthService) {
    return () => new Promise(resolve => {
        // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
        authService.refreshToken()
            .subscribe()
            .add(resolve);
    });
}
```

I've searched a lot on the internet how to solve this but I couldn't find anything. Hoping that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

> Documentation of

```
add(teardown: TeardownLogic): Subscription
```

> Adds a tear down to be called during the unsubscribe() of this Subscription.

In your code :

```
.subscribe().add(resolve);
```

This won't call the `resolve` function. Because there is no unsubscription logic in your code. And what you try to achieve is to resolve the promise as soon as `refreshToken()`  emits a value.

You can achieve this by directly calling `toPromise` :

```
  return () => authService.refreshToken().toPromise()
```

Comment: Thanks @Eldar, I just tested that, but I still have the same mistake.

Comment: @DidiersonAmuri did you observe any request made to `/users/refresh-token` in the network tab?

Comment: Hi @Eldar, sorry for answering you late, I looked in the network tab and this is what I found, by the way there are 2 refresh-token requests sent and one is not finished yet and has as message: CAUTION: request is not finished yet

Comment: and after a while still at network tab it displays an error: (failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, initiator zone-evergreen.js. That I don't understand

Comment: @DidiersonAmuri then there is something with your backend. Try to reproduce it with a tool like postman. See if you can reproduce the error. Check your request to see if your token send with in the header.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 13 and Rxjs 7.4, use:

```js
import { AuthService } from "@services/auth.service";
import { firstValueFrom } from "rxjs";

export function appInitializer(authService: AuthService) {
    return () => firstValueFrom(authService.refreshToken());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).